# Find and Remove Special Charecter In A Unix File

Tags: unix

I have a large file in Unix. At the end of that file I have a small right arrow. I would like to find and remove that arrow from the file. How would I go about doing this?

For example I have the following code... /usr/local/bin/unzip -jo MYFILE.ZIP > UNZIPPEDFILE.txt mv MYFILE.ZIP UNZIPPEDFILE.txt ----- I need to find and remove the little right arrow at the end of the unzipped file here. ------

Thank you for any help I receive.

Comment: You unzip a file and redirect stdout to a file which you then proceed to destroy by copying over it with the zip file.  Why bother with the unzipping?  And now you want to edit the renamed zip file??

Comment: I receive the file that is zipped. I need to unzip the file for downstream processing. After I unzip the file I have a right arrow on the last line of the file which I want to get rid off. I want to edit the file that I unzipped. the code should be .... mv myfile newfile.txt. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: So you are looking to edit UNZIPPEDFILE.txt or newfile.txt?  Are you also able to paste the last couple of lines in the question so we can see what we are dealing with?

Comment: I have the following Code... 
/usr/local/bin/unzip -jo MYFILE.ZIP > newfile.txt
mv MYFILE newfile.txt

I am looking to edit newfile.txt to remove the little right arrow on the last line of the file. I am unable to paste the little arrow on the last line from the file. It is not copying :(

Comment: I also believe the following is the hexadecimal for the right arrow I am receiving at end of file.... &#x2192

Comment: As it stands your code still makes no sense as you redirect to a file that you then blow away with what was extracted from the zip, but I guess that is your choice.  If you have the hexadecimal code you can then use that in sed or perl and should be able to have it deleted.  You should probably be able to do the same in an editor one would think.